# Not working if/else in one line Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

```
s_headers=[]
headers=['DRIVER’S NAME', 'LICENSE', 'PH NUMBER', 'DOB', 'HIRE DAY']
for head in headers:
    if isinstance(head, float):
        s_headers.append(str(int(head)))
    else:
        s_headers.append(head)
print(s_headers)
```

output:-

> ['DRIVER’S NAME', 'LICENSE', 'PH NUMBER', 'DOB', 'HIRE DAY']

when i am trying to reduce this code using this,

```
s_headers.append(str(int(head) if (isinstance(head, float)) else head) for head in headers)
print(s_headers)
```

output:-

> [ at 0x7f2aeec50780>]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

`s_headers.append(str(int(head) if (isinstance(head, float)) else head) for head in headers)`

creates a generator expression which does not evaluate members until they are needed. You can either do a list comprehension:

```
s_headers = [str(int(head) if (isinstance(head, float)) else head) for head in headers]
print(s_headers)
```

Or cast the result (the generator to a list):

`s_headers.extend(list(str(int(head) if (isinstance(head, float)) else head) for head in headers))`

Comment: deeper details !! @mrangry777

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
s_headers=[]
headers=['DRIVER’S NAME', 'LICENSE', 'PH NUMBER', 'DOB', 'HIRE DAY']

s_headers = [str(int(head)) if isinstance(head, float) else head  for head in headers]
print(s_headers)
```